# Adding events to Laminas

Tags: php, zend-framework3, laminas-api-tools, laminas

I am trying to add event for Laminas Framework that will fire when **\Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH** is triggered. But absolutelly nothing happends, like this triggers not exists. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code under the **module\Application\src\Module.php**:

```
use Laminas\ModuleManager\ModuleManager;
use Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)
    {
        ini_set("display_errors", '1');
        $eventManager = $moduleManager->getEventManager();
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, [$this, 'onDispatch']);
    }

    public function onDispatch(\Laminas\EventManager\Event $event)
    {
        var_dump('ok');die;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you need use another method in `Module` it's should be something like this:

```
use Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $application = $event->getApplication();
        $eventManager = $application->getEventManager();

        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, [$this, 'onDispatch']);
    }

    public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        var_dump('ok');
        die;
    }
}
```

In this case it `onBootstrap`. Hope help you

Answer (score 4):

On init you'll need to get the shared event manager from the module manager:

```php
<?php

use Laminas\ModuleManager\Feature\InitProviderInterface;
use Laminas\ModuleManager\ModuleManagerInterface;
use Laminas\Mvc\Application;
use Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent;

final class Module implements InitProviderInterface
{

    public function init(ModuleManagerInterface $manager): void
    {
        $sharedEventManager = $manager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
        $sharedEventManager->attach(
            Application::class,
            MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,
            function () {
                var_Dump('dispatch from init');
            }
        );
    }

}
```

*The `SharedEventManager` is usually (or should be) shared between all event manager instances.* This makes it possible to call or create events from other event manager instances. To differentiate between event names an identifier is used (so you can have more then one event with the same name). All MvcEvents belong to the `Laminas\Mvc\Application` identifier. `Laminas\ModuleManager\ModuleManager` has it's own EventManager instance, that is why you'll need to add the event to the SharedEventManager (`init()` is called by the ModuleManager and `Laminas\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent` is used).

`onBootstrap()` will be called by `Laminas\Mvc\Application`, that why you get the correct EventManager instance there.

As @Dimitry suggested: you should add that event in `onBootstrap()` as the dispatching process is part of the application and not the module manager. In `init()` you should only add bootstrap events.

And btw: [you should use the `Laminas\ModuleManager\Feature\*` interfaces](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-modulemanager/module-manager/#module-manager-listeners) to make your application a bit more robust to future updates.